# Compare JSON data before and after Codable conversion

Tags: json, swift, swift4, nsjsonserialization, codable

I've got `Data` object which contains JSON response from server.

It is converted to some `Codable` object this way:

```
let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(Object.self, from: response.data)
```

For testing purposes I would like to endcode this object back to `Data` and then compare to initial `Data`.

```
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
```

**1st assumption:** If `Data` objects are equal after decode + encode, it means that all the fields are correctly listed in my `Codable` `struct`, all fields have valid type and etc... After conversion I've got two `Data` objects: 154362 bytes 154435 bytes. It means that they are different. But when I compare them using [jsondiff.com](http://www.jsondiff.com) they appear to be 100% identical.

**2nd assumption**: I tried to convert Data objects to String, but JSON structures are sorted in different way... So this way doesn't work.

There is some issues with `Double` / `Float` values. They are interpreted this way during decoding: *41.01* results in *41.009999999*.

So the question is: Is there a way to validate that two JSON objects are identical before and after decode + encode?

**Current solution:** I decided to give `JSONSerialization` a try because since iOS 11 it has a great writing option:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public static var sortedKeys: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions { get }
```

This way I convert `Data` to a properly sorted json:

```
@available(iOS 11, *)
private extension Data {

    static func equal(json1: Data, json2: Data) -> Bool {
        return json1.serialized == json2.serialized
    }

    var serialized: Data? {
        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [.sortedKeys, .prettyPrinted]) else {
            return nil
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

Is it a reliable way to compare two json `Data` objects?

Comment: `JSONEncoder/Decoder` is very restrictive. Any inconsistency will throw an error. If the operation succeeds you can be sure that the data has been processed correctly. The input / output difference occurs only if floating point values are involved. if you need to control the precision of floating point values use `NumberFormatter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've create a small **iOS11** `Data` extension which helps me to compare JSON objects and find first line where any two JSON objects start to mismatch.

```
@available(iOS 11, *)
public extension Data {

    public func jsonSerialized() -> Data? {
        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        let object: Any = {
            if let array = json as? Array<Any> {
                return array.strippingNulls()
            } else if let dictionary = json as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                return dictionary.strippingNulls()
            } else {
                return json
            }
        }()
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: [.sortedKeys, .prettyPrinted]) else {
            return nil
        }
        return data
    }

    public static func jsonMismatch(lhs: Data, rhs: Data, alreadySerialized: Bool = false) -> Int? {
        switch alreadySerialized {
        case true:
            return _jsonMismatch(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs)
        case false:
            guard let lhs = lhs.jsonSerialized(), let rhs = rhs.jsonSerialized() else {
                return nil
            }
            return _jsonMismatch(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs)
        }
    }

    private static func _jsonMismatch(lhs: Data, rhs: Data) -> Int? {
        guard let string1 = String(data: lhs, encoding: .utf8), let string2 = String(data: rhs, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        let components1 = string1.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        let components2 = string2.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        let count = components1.count < components2.count ? components1.count : components2.count
        for index in 0 ..< count {
            if components1[index] != components2[index] {
                return index
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

private extension Array where Element == Any {

    func strippingNulls() -> Array {
        var array = self
        array.stripNulls()
        return array
    }

    mutating func stripNulls() {
        let count = self.count
        guard count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        for _index in 0 ..< count {
            let index = count - 1 - _index
            if self[index] is NSNull {
                remove(at: index)
            } else if let array = self[index] as? [Any] {
                self[index] = array.strippingNulls()
            } else if let dictionary = self[index] as? [String: Any] {
                self[index] = dictionary.strippingNulls()
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {

    func strippingNulls() -> Dictionary {
        var dictionary = self
        dictionary.stripNulls()
        return dictionary
    }

    mutating func stripNulls() {
        for (key, value) in self {
            if value is NSNull {
                removeValue(forKey: key)
            } else if let array = value as? [Any] {
                self[key] = array.strippingNulls()
            } else if let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] {
                self[key] = dictionary.strippingNulls()
            }
        }
    }
}
```